# Using Nginx as proxy for my SSL protected API server

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx

I'm struggling to find a solution to this, or even get information if it is even possible.

I have a NodeJS backend, which currently accesses APIs on a SSL protected server (let's call it https://whatever.com).

I would like to proxy those http calls through Nginx so I could better collect rich log data, which is very easy for to get from Nginx. (Not so easy from Node, which would require a change in the backend, plugins and whatnot).

It seems, from the "solutions" I've found, that this is not possible unless I have a domain name to use for this Nginx, so I could get a proper (and not self-signed) certificate. Is this accurate? It is only an internal webserver, to proxy outgoing connections, it would not be publicly available.

If I do something and straightfoward (which I would if it was pure 'http') as

```
upstream apigw {
    server whatever.com:443;
}

server {
    listen 8088;
    server_name nodeapiproxy;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://apigw;
    }
}
```

I get a weird 'Unknown domain' error which tells me very little.

Ideally, I would like to make port-80 calls to this Nginx, and it would forward them to whatever.com. But port-443-https would be fine too, if only I could get it working with a self-signed certificate or, even better, with no certificate at all.

Comment: Can the NodeJS backend (server) resolve nodeapiproxy? If it couldn't resolve, add it to hosts file. nodeipproxy:8088 can be on HTTP - just have to change the NodeJS backend to call `http://nodeipproxy:8088`. The proxy_pass has to be HTTPS.

Comment: Where do you get this error? Also is your `whatever.com` domain public?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my hosts file and Nginx can resolve the name with no problem. Yes, whatever.com is public.
I get the error when I try to call it from curl or wget.